# Selecting CourseWork for specific date (Classroom API)

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to obtain all incomplete assignments for a specific date. I've found that you can utilize the Google Calendar API to access the assignments as events within a date range, although you are unable to view the status (complete, incomplete, pending) of the assignment. Hopefully there is an alternative method to accessing this sort of data.

Comment: It sounds like the problem you're talking about is very specific to the domain you're working in and I'm not sure we're going to be able to help without a bit more info. How are assignments stored in Google Calendar with a status?

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. Each classroom page has a calendar for it. With the calendar you can select a specific date range of assignments. My issue is that classroom doesn't store CourseWork Ids within these calendar events.